# How do I pass multiple variables to VBS Send Keys from an Excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, sendkeys

So I currently am working on a macro that detects when an email is received in outlook, gets the sending information and copies the email content. From here I have an excel spreadsheet setup to check the user against, if it finds the user listed I have a sendkeys script to log a job in our helpdesk system.

The issue I am having is passing multiple variables to my sendkeys script.

Here is how I am passing it over from the excel macro:

```
strParam1 = AssystID 
strParam2 = Sheets("Ext Database").Range("G3").Value
strVBSPath = "C:\Scripts\testsofar.vbs"
Shell ("wscript.exe " & strVBSPath & " " & strParam1 & strParam2)
```

`strParam1` is a username (e.g KIERANL) from the database and `strParam2`  is the Item type (e.g Internal) I am logging it against.

The problem I am having is getting the correct output from the SendKeys script. Currently I am using the line: `WshShell.SendKeys Wscript.Arguments(0)`
which I believe should send over `strParam1`, however when I am passing across multiple values it is combining them such as the examples above it would send: `KIERANLINTERNAL` all on one line.

My question is what exactly am I doing incorrectly? I have looked at this page: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692833.aspx and I cannot see exactly what is wrong with my method.

Comment: How is that article even relevant it doesn't even mention `SendKeys()`?

Comment: But it does mention Wscript Arguments, I figured they would be the same method using SendKeys. Am I getting confused with two different things?

Comment: `Arguments` is a collection of what gets passed into the script as command line arguments so for example `wscript.exe test.vbs 1, test, "test 2"` would give a `Arguments` collection containing `1`, `test` and `test 2`. `SendKeys()` is used to send keystrokes *(as if typed on the keyboard)* to the active window.

Comment: So the issue is with my method. How would I go about passing the above values I have stated to my `SendKeys` script?

Comment: I'm not saying that at this point is difficult to see what the problem is without a [mcve].

Comment: What about placing a comma between your values at the moment they will be seen as one value? Try, `Shell ("wscript.exe " & strVBSPath & " " & strParam1 & ", " & strParam2)` Before your command was being executed as `wscript.exe C:\Scripts\testsofar.vbs  KIERANLINTERNAL` you see the issue?, it should be `wscript.exe C:\Scripts\testsofar.vbs  KIERANL, INTERNAL`.

Comment: That's cracked it pretty much, Lanky. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think from what you have described the problem is the lack of separation between the arguments you are passing.

At the moment your command looks like this when passed

```
wscript.exe C:\Scripts\testsofar.vbs KIERANLINTERNAL
```

The problem being the two parameters have merged into one when actually you want this

```
wscript.exe C:\Scripts\testsofar.vbs KIERANL, INTERNAL
```

To do this in the code just concatenate a comma between your two arguments like this

```vb
Shell ("wscript.exe " & strVBSPath & " " & strParam1 & ", " & strParam2)
```